# imap_fetchbody vs Gmail api get method

Tags: php, encryption, imap, gmail-api, mbox

The return format of html [imap_fetchbody](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php) vs [Gmail api GET](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) method are different.

I write the emails to a file and then re-import into Thunderbird. With `imap_fetchbody` written emails are loaded into **Thunderbird** with no padding issues while the same email returned by the **API** has padding issue.

The most difference I see is **3D**.

Here's a few lines from `imap_fetchbody`:

```
<html lang=3Den><head><meta content=3D"date=3Dno" name=3D"format-detection"=
><meta content=3D"email=3Dno" name=3D"format-detection"><style>.awl a {colo=
r: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}.abml a {color: #000000; font-family: Ro=
boto-Medium,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-decoration:=
 none;}.adgl a {color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); text-decoration: none;}.afal a =
{color: #b0b0b0; text-decoration: none;}@media screen and (min-width: 600px=
) {.v2sp {padding: 6px 30px 0px;} .v2rsp {padding: 0px 10px;}}</style></hea=
d>
```

And a few lines from `GMAIL api GET` method:

```
<html lang=en><head><meta content="date=no" name="format-detection"><meta 
 content="email=no" name="format-detection"><style>.awl a {color: #FFFFFF; 
 text-decoration: none;}.abml a {color: #000000; font-family: Roboto-
 Medium,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: 
 none;}.adgl a {color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); text-decoration: none;}.afal a 
 {color: #b0b0b0; text-decoration: none;}@media screen and (min-width: 
 600px) {.v2sp {padding: 6px 30px 0px;} .v2rsp {padding: 0px 10px;}}</style> 
 </head>`
```

While `Gmail api GET` method returns `base64 encode` version which I converts the following way:

```
function decode($data)
{
    return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}
```

What really is difference between both and why really is the difference?

[Screen shot of the mail fetched through gmail api](http://screencast.com/t/PHt4jn6x)

[Screen shot of the mail fetched through imap_fetchbody](http://screencast.com/t/PcfjqvwcAAH)

Your comments and answers will be appreicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between both is that the `imap_fetchbody` returns:

> It's quoted-printable text, probably the result of passing through a "dumb" mail client. = is used to encode/escape unprintable/metacharacters, much like &...; is used in HTML.
>   =3d is the quoted-printable representation of an =: 3d hex = 61 ascii = equals sign.

Reference: [imap_fetchbody HTML with strange chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297274/imap-fetchbody-html-with-strange-chars)

While `Gmail api GET` method returns `base64_encoded` string which needs to be `decoded`. We can add the same `quoted-printable` effect by just:

```
quoted_printable_encode($string)
```